# 'Builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable. Error while using NumPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-slicing

I am new fo NumPy and was creating a script to count the number of each vovels in a word. By far I have comeup with this solution for counting all the vovels:

```
import numpy as np
num = 0
name = np.array['B','A', 'N', 'A', 'N', 'A']
print(name)
vovel = np.array['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']
for i in (0,4):
    a = name[i:i+1]
    if a in vovel:
        num = num+1
    
print(num)
```

But this code give Type error again and again. Can you please explain what is wrong and also how can I change it to make it show number of times each vovel occurs.

Comment: You have to put parentheses around the lists.

Comment: `name = np.array(['B','A', 'N', 'A', 'N', 'A'])`

Comment: Thanks but how do I count the vovels. Still stuck on that

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the error message. But without seeing the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something a little more like this:

For each vowel (<strike>vovel</strike>), check the vowel against each letter in name, and print the count at the end of the loop.

```
import numpy as np

name = np.array(['B', 'A', 'N', 'A', 'N', 'A'])
vowels = np.array(['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'])

print(name)

for vowel in vowels:
    count = 0

    for letter in name:
        if letter == vowel:
            count += 1

    print(f'{vowel}: {count}')
```

It's also worth mentioning, in Python strings are ***iterable***, meaning you can iterate over them.  This means instead of passing a numpy array of

```
['B', 'A', 'N', 'A', 'N', 'A']
```

you could actually just pass the string

```
'BANANA'
```

and you will achieve the same results

Comment: Also just realised I missed your actual question, but as already answered by @Klaus_D you're missing the () around your np.array calls